# Removing duplicates from array ( understand the code)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking at an exercise and having trouble understand how the following works ( I'm trying to remove duplicates from an array)

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','a','b','d','e','f'];
var uniqueArray = arr.filter(function(item,pos){
   return arr.indexOf(item) == pos; 
});
```

**My attempt to understand**

Here `item` takes on all of our values in `arr`. Lets go through an iteration
`First item = 'a'` and `pos = 0`. Ok. now we want to only filter on the basis of if the index of `'a'`is the same as `0`

Here `indexOf(a) == 0`.

Great! this is true, lets put it in the new array.

Now lets move forward to where we see a again, namely at `pos = 3`

```
arr.indexOf(a) == 3
```

Wait... Doesent this meet our requirement as well? How does this even remove duplicates?

Comment: IF current element is having the index as first index of the element in the same array then keep it. If not, i.e. index are different, then it means there are multiple elements having same value. Remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` returns just one integer value, and it is the index of the first found item. So, when `pos` is 3 (and the `item` is `a`), `indexOf` will return 0 (because the first index of `a` is 0), `0==3` is false and the element will be removed.

Then, when the `pos` is 4 (and `item` is `b`), `indexOf` returns 2, the index of the first found `b`.

---

As for the objects, they can't have duplicate keys. Each new key will automatically overwrite the old one, so there won't be any duplicates.

Look:

```js
var obj = {a:1, a:3, b:2,c:5,b:4};
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: how does indexOf know how to get the index of the first found item, is that how it was just created?

Comment: @cres Not sure what you're asking for... `indexOf` was created to return the index of the first found element, yes.

Comment: Oh. so basically no matter how many a's there are, indexOf(a) will point to the index of the first one, i.e 0?

Comment: @cres To the index of the first found one.

Comment: @cres See the edit, maybe it will clarify the things.

Comment: Thanks , I  get it. Could I extend this to objects? say obj = {a:1, a:3, b:2,c:5,d"6| has two a properties

Comment: @cres It's impossible for an object to have duplicate keys. Each new key will overwrite the next one.

Comment: Hmm, what if they had the same values? say obj = {a:1, b:1, c:3,d:4}, can we filter based on the type values? i.e remove b:1 since we already had a:1

Comment: @cres Uh, please ask another question. That's really going too far from the problem, this specific question has already been answered.

Comment: @cres if you want that answered ask another question

Comment: If you are happy there, they both got the point across. No need to be stingy about virtual points. Thanks for your help

Comment: @cres I didn't *mean* to say that. I do actually think that the answer by kag359six is indeed better, and wanted to excuse. It also contains the note to search from the certain index, mine doesn't. If it does look that embarassing, sorry again - you could remove the checkmark and I'll remove my answer then, no worries (can't delete the answer if it has the checkmark).

Comment: @cresjoy its not about the points, it's about the websites format. Other people may have similar questions as you and it is helpful to them if you make it a separate question. I apologize if I came across as rude.

Answer (score 1):

nicael is right. `indexOf(item)` is just a function that goes through the array and looks for the first time `item` appears in the array, and returns the position in the array. In your example, if there is an `a` at 0 and `a` at index 3, then `indexOf('a')` will return position 0, while the value of `pos` is 3, so the filter returns false.

FOLLOW UP:

`indexOf()` has another parameter called the fromIndex, which lets you start the search from a position other than the beginning of the array. In this case, you can specify to skip over the first time `'a'` occurs by doing `arr.indexOf('a', 1)` which starts the search at position 1, not 0. In this case the function would return true since the next `'a'` is at position 3.

***Can I use filter on an object?***

No, because filter is a specific function of an Array object. You can get the keys of the object by doing a filter on `Object.keys(myObject)` since keys() returns an array.

Using your example:

```
var keyArray = Object.keys(myObject); //object can't have duplicate keys

keyArray.filter(function(item, index) {

    return keyArray.indexOf(item) == index; //will never be false 

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I get it now + 1. Could I do the same process for objects? Say   obj = {a:1, a:3, b:2,c:5,d:6} has two a properties , and now I want to remove it

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense to filter the keys because they are automatically de-duplicated.

Comment: In his specific case, no it makes no sense at all. But there may be some cases where you want to filter out certain keys possibly.

Answer (score -1):

Hashtable is the best way to eliminate the redundant values
Here is the code :

```
char arr[] = ['a','b','c','a','b','d','e','f'];
//it will contains all 26 places as zero (A - Z)
char hashArray[26]={0} 
int i; //for iteration;

for(i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++)
{
  //it will subtracte the ascii value of the letter 
  //from 'a' so that we have the values from 0 to 26)
  hashArray[arr[i]-'a']=arr[i]; 
}

for(i=0;i<26;i++)
{
   if(hashArray[i]!=0) //to Ensure the positon has the character
   {
      printf("%c",hashArray[i]); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: This was supposed to be the question, right? Why do you post an answer to a random question?